# C# .NET dynamic form controls or wpf templates

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dynamic

In a WPF application, I would like to display a grid of tiles (buttons essentially) using images from a folder location. There could be any different number of images in the folder, so the tiles/buttons need to be generated dynamically and formatted based on the amount. These need to be buttons that can trigger mouse click events.

I'm very new to C# and .NET, so I'd just like some direction on what the best way of doing this would be. I've started this as a WPF application so would using a template be a good idea? Or if just dynamically creating form buttons with background images is an easy option then I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for `ItemsControl`. You need a class representing your buttons, with properties such as X, Y, ImageUri, and so on. You expose your generated buttons via `ObservableCollection` and bind it to `ItemsSource` of your `ItemsControl`. Then you change your `ItemsPanelTemplate` to grid:

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>                        
                    <!--Here go rows and columns definitions-->
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>                
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

If you have fixed number of rows and columns, you may add them directly in XAML, otherwise generate them at runtime in code-behind. You add `ItemsContainerStyle` for positioning:

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding X}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Also, you need `ItemTemplate` which will cover displaying button with image. Other options would be to use `Canvas` or `UniformGrid` as `ItemsPanelTemplate` (both with their advantages and disadvantages).

Comment: Thanks amnezjak, I managed to Google enough keywords from this and brute-force my way into getting it working.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need a ItemsControl such as a ListView. Unfortunately WPF only ships the GridView implementation, but the ListView was intended to support all those views you see in the Windows file explorer. For a Tiled based view you would need to override the ViewBase class and assign it to the View property of the ListView.

Years ago I have had sample code that demonstrated what you want.

The following link contains MSDN samples: 
[MSDN ListView.View samples](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=160013)

[How to: Create a Custom View Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859.aspx%5D%20%5B2%5D)

I know that the Xceed DataGrid has a built-in CardView mode. I don't know if it is available in the free version: [Xceed WPF DataGrid documentation](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfDataGrid/)

**Edit** I just checked the MSDN samples and I think they are close to what you want.